# Dropout after the Embeding layer

Tags: nlp, lstm

I am working on a classification problem. I am using pre-trained GloVe word embedding as input I wanted to know whether adding a dropout after the embedding layer makes sense at all? I have seen a lot of notebooks on Kaggle where dropout layers are added after the embedding layer and were wondering why this is done.

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size+1,embedding_dim,input_length=max_len, weights=[embeddings_matrix],trainable=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64,return_sequences= True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458902/does-applying-a-dropout-layer-after-the-embedding-layer-have-the-same-effect-as

Comment: I get the explanation on the above link but that doesn't explain does it make sense to add a dropout layer after the embedding layer or after an LSTM layer which is a better practice?